How to add an HTML + CSS overlay to a DirectX app?
I'm looking for a way to render html and css elements within an executable as an overlay.
There are programs today made in electron such as Blitz or even the best known Discord. They do overlay within the executable, which apparently uses HTML + css + javascript.
Does anyone know how this can be done?

Searching for "directx html css" turns up libraries like Awesomium (now Ultralight), DevExpress, and sciter that provide this functionality.

Please expand upon the term overlay.  AFIK, the web apps are simply custom browsers serving local wrapper pages for online content.
